# i want to use controller(i.e i want to use JSON data for templateUrl of routeProvider) inside routeProvider in app.js

Tags: html, angularjs

This is a part of my code in app.js(angular file). There in template url, i want to load data from JSON.

```
    var app = angular.module('infonion_org', []);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {       
          $routeProvider.when('/', {    
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          activetab: 'home'
        }).when('/projects', { templateUrl: 'projects.html', activetab: 'projects'}).
        when('/projects/:projectId', {
          templateUrl: function (params) { return '' + params.projectId + '.html'; },

          activetab: 'projects'
        }).
        when('/about', {
          templateUrl: 'about.html',          
          activetab: 'about'
        })
    }])


Please help me solve this..
```

Comment: What is the problem that you have - what needs to be solved? What have you tried so far?

Comment: hai @OllyCruickshank. i have been in process of developing website with angular js. Im getting correct output now. But for some cases, i want to load some url's from a JSON where those url's are there. Please tell me how to load JSON inside(templateUrl:[some json here]) that code i have shown above.